# How to solve error `Missing Authentication Token`

Tags: aws-lambda, nestjs

I have published my NestJS app to the AWS Lambda

When I try to open the root URL

```
https://xxx/
```

it shows "Hello World" correctly

But when I open up :

```
https://xxx/sales/subscription
```

it shows `Missing Authentication Token` message

Has anyone experienced this kind of issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue, I'm sharing the solution here, hopefully, it helps anyone having the same issue.

So, apparently `Missing Authentication Token` means the route does not exist.

The app was deployed to AWS Lambda using the serverless framework.

I fixed the issue by simply opening the `serverless.yaml` file, and then registered the route in the `functions` section.
Before :

```
functions:
 main: # The name of the lambda function
   # The module 'handler' is exported in the file 'src/lambda'
   handler: src/lambda.handler
   events:
     - http:
         method: any
         path: /
```

After :

```
functions:
 main: # The name of the lambda function
   # The module 'handler' is exported in the file 'src/lambda'
   handler: src/lambda.handler
   events:
     - http:
         method: any
         path: /
     - http:
         method: any
         path: /sales/subscription
```